# Edit ArrayCollection through Item Renderer

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, data-binding, itemrenderer, bindable

I use a spark `List` with a custom item renderer and an `ArrayCollection` for `dataProvider`.

The ItemRenderer looks something like

```
<mx:TextInput id="txtValue1" text="{data.myFirstValue}"/>
<mx:TextInput id="txtValue2" text="{data.mySecondValue}"/>
```

However, even though I change the text in `txtValue1` or `txtValue2`, those are not actually changed in the object inside the ArrayCollection.

`myFirstValue` and `mySecondValue` are decorated with the `[Bindable]` tag.

My understanding is that if the `text` property is set to be bound a certain property, the changes should be automatically applied.

So the **HACK** (or so I think) that I use is to listen to the `focusOut` event of each textbox, and access the parent data provider and set the the values manually.

What am I doing wrong? Is it supposed to work like this?

Or what did I understand wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, binding in flex is one-way.  In other words, changes in your `data` object are updated in the UI but not the other way around.

You need to use 2-way binding.  This is very easy since Flex 4.0.  Notice the use of the "@" sign:

```
<mx:TextInput id="txtValue1" text="@{data.myFirstValue}"/>
<mx:TextInput id="txtValue2" text="@{data.mySecondValue}"/>
```

Now, any changes made to the `TextInput` will get pushed down to the `data` object as well.

Read more about [Two way data binding](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_How_to_use_two_way_data_binding_in_Flex_4-15946.html).

Comment: Damn! :O That actually did the trick! Oh why didn't I know of this before! :S Thanx so much!

Comment: @Brian: I updated your answer to put more information. Hope you don't mind :)

Comment: @Ranhiru: I removed the statement "Use caution with two-way binding because initially empty TextInput etc. can wipe out data in data models." because I am not sure I understand it... I use 2-way binding all the time but have never run into a problem like this.  Under what circumstances does this happen?

Comment: @Brian: That was copied from a comment in the same article I added. I am yet to come across such a problem. But the way I understood was that because it is two-way bound, when a text box is loaded without any text, the data model can become empty as well. I thought adding that might be a caution to another user.

Comment: @Ranhiru: I suppose this is the type of thing where I wouldn't consider using it if the behavior were non-deterministic.  In my experience, 2-way binding always takes the data from data model and not vice-versa.  I'd love to see examples of how the opposite can happen, but I prefer to keep it out of my answer because it isn't a problem, in my experience.